# Получение ANDROID_ID на всех версиях Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Подскажите пожалуйста как в Android на всех версиях получать ANDROID_ID, чтобы для конкретного устройства он некогда не менялся. И на другом устройстве нельзя было сгенерировать такой же id

Comment: *чтобы для конкретного устройства он некогда не менялся* значит, нужна некая физическая характеристика устройства. MAC, IMEI, ...

Comment: насколько я знаю в настоящее время гугл запрещает использовать реальные идентификаторы устройства

Comment: Хэшируй. И необратимо, и оригинально, если длина хэша достаточна.

Comment: вопрос в другом на последних версиях андроид это значение получить не реально или я не знаю как, подскажите пожалуйста какой нибудь пример где наглядно показано как выдернуть это значение

Comment: @LEON read_phone_state пермишен нужен. тогда можно imei получить.

Comment: Использовал ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>``` и метод ```getDeviceId()``` он устарел вместо него надо использовать метод ```getImei()``` с последним не удалось получить данные. в первом случае получилось получить только на android 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для получения ANDROID_ID можно использовать`String androidID = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);` это значение будет меняться только после сброса настроек к заводским

Comment: не советую) начиная с 8 андроида он выдаёт случайную строку, которая в каждом приложении разная. Ну или вопрос просто составлен.

Comment: мне это нужно для защиты токена авторизации одного приложения я думаю этого будет достаточно, если при отправке токена и девайс ид, девайс ид придет другой то пользователя попросят заново авторизоваться